# How can we set the YouTube popup align the center and set the popup height and width using `import ModalVideo from "react-modal-video" in react JS?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to YouTube popup align the center and set the popup height and width using `import ModalVideo from "react-modal-video"; If I am click on the button the open youtube player in left side above style attribute is not working

**Source code:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ModalVideo from "react-modal-video";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";

export default function Index(){
    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false)
      return(
        <div id="mainBackground" className="master-container">
        <Header/>
        <main className="content-featured">
            <h1 className="txt-light-xxl-white text-center"><nobr>aaaa</nobr> graphics in minutes</h1>
            <h2 className="txt-book-fs21-gray text-center">bbbb</h2>
            <div className="modalvideo">
                <ModalVideo channel="youtube" isOpen={isOpen} videoId="nu3qgYef2uM" onClose={() => setOpen(false)} classNames="youtube-player" styles={{modal: {maxWidth: '800px', width: '80%', minHeight: '480px', }}}/>
            </div>
            <div className="youtube">
                <button className="youtube-btn text-uppercase" onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>View Intro <img src="images/play-icon.png" className="play-icon"/></button>
            </div>
            
        </main>
        <Footer/>
    </div>
)
```

}

Image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOsPJ.jpg)

youtube players should be aligned center and how set the height and width in `ModalVideo` element.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWCNC.png)

Answer (score 0):

To specify modal styles, an object called **modalStyles** has been added. try below code i hope solve your issue.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ModalVideo from "react-modal-video";


export default function Index() {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const modalStyles = {
    content: {
      top: "50%",
      left: "50%",
      right: "auto",
      bottom: "auto",
      marginRight: "-50%",
      transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
      maxWidth: "800px",
      width: "80%",
      minHeight: "480px",
    },
  };

  return (
    <div className="master-container">
      <div className="modalvideo">
        <ModalVideo
          channel="youtube"
          isOpen={isOpen}
          videoId="nu3qgYef2uM"
          onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
          classNames="youtube-player"
          styles={modalStyles}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="youtube">
        <button className="youtube-btn text-uppercase" onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
          View Intro <img src="images/play-icon.png" className="play-icon" alt="Play icon" />
        </button>
      </div>
      </main>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank's Mahesh - As suggested I tried this but not solve this issue if I click on the button and then open it on the left top.

Comment: I think `ModalVideo` property is fixed, please see the image link I edited the question.